# How can I enter a parameter composed of multiple paths in the terminal of powershell？

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am a newbie learning powershell.
I wrote a script to clean up expired files on a regular basis, and I plan to run it in jenkins.
When I pass a path, it's fine, and it works fine.

code:

```
PS D:\clean-task> powershell D:\clean-task\clean-up.ps1  -WORKSPACE_LIST D:\clean-task\test  -LOG_FLODER_PATH D:\clean-task  -LIMIT_DAY 0
```

But when I pass 2 spliced ones, it doesn’t work.

code:

```
PS D:\clean-task> powershell D:\clean-task\clean-up.ps1  -WORKSPACE_LIST "D:\clean-task\test,D:\clean-task\test1"  -LOG_FLODER_PATH D:\clean-task  -LIMIT_DAY 0
```

So how can I enter a string parameter composed of multiple paths in the terminal of powershell?

Comment: you need to make sure the script parameter accepts more than one thing. to get more detailed help, you will likely need to follow the rules here and present a minimal, concise, working bit of code to demo your problem. lookee ... How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its not a direct answer...but first I would look if there is a plugin for Jenkins which does the job for you. Maybe this one will fit your needs: https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/. If not you can loop in Jenkins over your files and fire your script multiple times

Comment: Change your paths from a single string to an array (eg: `"D:\clean-task\test","D:\clean-task\test1"` instead of what you got.). While at it, make sure that your target script have the same typo than your call for the LOG_FOLDER_PATH, or LOG_FLODER_PATH). Otherwise you'll have issues there too.

Comment: It works for me as an array only as -command (the default) not -file, with or without quotes, within cmd or powershell.  But I don't know Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the `-File` logo after the powershell command.
I think this will actually treat the following parameters as strings and pass them to the executed `.ps1` file.

Comment: I don't see how that would work unless you're splitting the string into 2 paths yourself.

Comment: `foreach ($workspace in $WORKSPACE_LIST.Split(',')) {
    Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate $workspace
  }
`